# Android Studio windows not showing

Tags: java, android-studio, window

My problem is that the windows for viewing the project before it starts are no longer shown. How can I fix this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqXG9.png)

Comment: did you try to make an invalidate cache and restart ?

Comment: you can try build -> clean code

Comment: didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Allow your Gradle to finish running first then check to know whether it will open, if it didn't open, click on the error message with red exclamation mark at your right hand side above the question mark sign then post the error message so that people will know the cause of the problem. This error might also be as a result of missing file or component so all you need to do is connect to the internet then close and open your studio again then wait for Gradle to download any missing file or components.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.